# How to sort keys in multidimensional dict

Tags: python

I have multidimensional dict:

```
my_dict = {
    "first": {
        "bbb": "aaa",
        "ccc": "sdfs",
        "aaa": "123"
    },
    "other": {
        "ttt": "a",
        "e": "e",
        "yy": "y"
    },
    "aaa": {
        "q": "a",
        "e": "e",
        "r": "y"
    }
}
```

I would like to sort the second dimension in this dictionary based on the keys alphabetically.
I would like to receive:

```
my_new_dict = {
    "first": {
        "aaa": "123",
        "bbb": "aaa",
        "ccc": "sdfs"
    },
    "other": {
        "e": "e",
        "ttt": "a",
        "yy": "y"
    },
    "aaa": {
        "e": "e",
        "q": "a",
        "r": "y"
    }
}
```

I have tried:

```
my_new_dict = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: lambda y: y[0])
```

but this return me error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sorted` for each of the sub-dictionaries:

```py
my_dict = { "first": { "bbb": "aaa", "ccc": "sdfs", "aaa": "123" }, "other": { "ttt": "a", "e": "e", "yy": "y" }, "aaa": { "q": "a", "e": "e", "r": "y" } }

output = {k: dict(sorted(v.items())) for k, v in my_dict.items()}

print(output)
# {'first': {'aaa': '123', 'bbb': 'aaa', 'ccc': 'sdfs'},
#  'other': {'e': 'e', 'ttt': 'a', 'yy': 'y'},
#  'aaa': {'e': 'e', 'q': 'a', 'r': 'y'}}
```

Note that "sorting" of a dict is guaranteed to work only for python 3.7+.